# Sending a ArrayList in a generic Collection method

Tags: java, generics

I have this as a method

```
public <E> Collection<E> toCollection(E[] a)
```

What I do not know is what does `E[]` mean? and how would you go about sending a `ArrayList` to this method?

thanks in advance.

Comment: For the record, an `ArrayList` *is* a `Collection`.

Answer (score 0):

`E[]` means that the function expects an array of objects of type `E`. `E` is a generic type.
See [here](https://www.techiedelight.com/creating-generic-array-java/) for more info.

You cannot send an `ArrayList` to that method, because an `ArrayList` is not an `Array`. It's also already a `Collection`, so it would make no sense to use that method with an ArrayList.

*Why is it a Collection?* Because it **implements** the [Collection](http://Collection%3CE%3E) interface.
If that method is meant to turn an array into a `Collection`, then you can see how turining an ArrayList into an Array just so you can send it through there would be a bad idea.

Still, if you already know what that E **is** specifically (what type it will be when you run the program) you can of course still turn the arraylist into an array and send it through the method.

Comment: It's possible to convert the list to an array, but only if you have the runtime type of `E`.

Comment: @shmosel I'll edit the answer to be clear on why that's possible, while still probably being a bad idea